# django-dropbox - cannot serialize

Tags: python, django, dropbox

I wanted to try `django-dropbox` to upload images directly to dropbox.

This is the model

```
from django_dropbox.storage import DropboxStorage

STORAGE = DropboxStorage()

class Drop(models.Model):

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', storage=STORAGE,null=True, blank=True)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes', storage=STORAGE,null=True, blank=True)
```

But when i try to migrate i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 124, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 152, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 131, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 82, in serialize
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 263, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 333, in serialize
    return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 239, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 409, in serialize
    "topics/migrations/#migration-serializing" % value
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <django_dropbox.storage.DropboxStorage object at 0xa01db4c>
```